# Explanation of 8-Queen solution Java code.

Tags: java, backtracking, n-queens

I found a 8-Queen solution that I was able to compile and run in Eclipse. I believe this solution follows the backtracking approach and meat of the work is done in the `solution` and `unsafe` functions, but I am having a hard time understanding the code paths in there. Can someone please help me understand what this code is doing.

My Source - http://rosettacode.org/wiki/N-queens_problem#Java
I verified the output against the 92 solutions published on other sources. Looks good. So I know the code works.

I have tried to format it and add some basic notes to clear things up -

```
private static int[] b = new int[8];
private static int s = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // solution from - http://rosettacode.org/wiki/N-queens_problem#Java
    new QueenN();
}

public QueenN() {
    solution();
}

public void solution() {
    int y = 0;
    b[0] = -1;
    while (y >= 0) {
        do {
            b[y]++;
        } while ((b[y] < 8) && unsafe(y));

        if (b[y] < 8) {

            if (y < 7) {
                b[++y] = -1;
            } else {
                putboard();
            }

        } else {
            y--;
        }
    }
}

// check if queen placement clashes with other queens
public static boolean unsafe(int y) {
    int x = b[y];
    for (int i = 1; i <= y; i++) {
        int t = b[y - i];
        if (t == x || t == x - i || t == x + i) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// printing solution
public static void putboard() {
    System.out.println("\n\nSolution " + (++s));
    for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
            if (b[y] == x)
                System.out.print("|Q");
            else
                System.out.print("|_");
        }
        System.out.println("|");
    }
}
```

End.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to understand the code step by step. First of all, we call the function solution(), which is what leads to the execution of the puzzle answer.

Solution funcion:

```
public void solution() {
    int y = 0;
    b[0] = -1;
    while (y >= 0) {
        do {
            b[y]++; //if last cell was unsafe or we reached the end of the board, we go for the next row.
        } while ((b[y] < 8) && unsafe(y)); //Checks whether it's the last cell and if it's an unsafe cell (clashing)

        if (b[y] < 8) { //We found a safe cell. Hooray!

            if (y < 7) { //Did we place the last queen?
                b[++y] = -1; //Nope, let's allocate the next one.
            } else {
                putboard(); //Yup, let's print the result!
            }

        } else { //If not a single safe cell was found, we reallocate the last queen.
            y--;
        }
    }
}
```

On the first while, you're going to iterate through each cell in a row (or column, however you prefer it. It's just a rotation matter). On each cell you make the unsafe(y) check, which will return true in case the cell you're placing the queen in is clashing with other queen-occupied cells (as you've already found out in the comment).

Next step, once we've found a safe cell in which to place the actual queen (y), we make a security check: if we have not found a single safe cell for that queen, we have to reallocate last queen.

In case the cell was found and was correct, we check whether it was the last queen (y < 7). If it is so, we proceed to print the result. Otherwise, we just re-start the while loop by placing b[++y] = -1.

Unsafe function:

```
public static boolean unsafe(int y) {
    int x = b[y]; //Let's call the actual cell "x"
    for (int i = 1; i <= y; i++) { //For each queen before placed BEFORE the actual one, we gotta check if it's in the same row, column or diagonal.
        int t = b[y - i];
        if (t == x || t == x - i || t == x + i) {
            return true; //Uh oh, clash!
        }
    }
    return false; //Yay, no clashes!
}
```

This function checks whether the queen we're using clashes with any of the allocated queens before this one. The clashes might happen diagonally, vertically or horizontally: That is why there is a triple OR check before the "return true" statement.

Putboard function:

```
public static void putboard() {
    System.out.println("\n\nSolution " + (++s));
    for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
            if (b[y] == x)
                System.out.print("|Q");
            else
                System.out.print("|_");
        }
        System.out.println("|");
    }
}
```

I'm not gonna explain this one that deep, because it is simply a fairly simply line printing function which you can find out how it works by yourself when executing the solution!

Hope this helps.

Cheers!